# How to set .HRef for a Hyperlink which is inside a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

Inside a `Repeater` I have an `hyperlink` in the item template.

```
<ItemTemplate>
<li>
<a runat="server" id="repLink">
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSub"></asp:Label>    
</a>
</li>
</ItemTemplate>
```

in the code behind, `OnItemDataBound` I am accessing it with following code:

```
HyperLink repLink = (HyperLink) e.Item.FindControl("repLink");
```

Now I want to set the `href` for this hyperlink `repLink`.
But I cannot use **`.HRef`** ?

```
repLink.HRef = "https:\\google.com";
```

The above line gives me syntax error:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'HRef'

I even tried with `Link` but still the same error.

```
Link repLink = (Link) e.Item.FindControl("repLink");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are used `HyperLink` that is ASP.NET server control, So you should use [`HyperLink.NavigateUrl Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.navigateurl(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
repLink.NavigateUrl = "https:\\google.com";
```

If you want to have `href attribute` you should use [`HtmlAnchor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor?view=netframework-4.8) that is HTML control like this:

```
HtmlAnchor repLink = (HtmlAnchor)e.Item.FindControl("repLink");
repLink.HRef = "https:\\google.com";
```